# SQL2008 geography query to JPG

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial

I'd like to take the results of a SQL geographic query, and create a JPG - something similar to what you see in the 'spatial view' tab.

I'm doing this for 200+ query, so something I can automate could be nice.  Does an app already exist to do this, or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get some mileage out of looking at the latest version of SQL Server Reporting Services. It has been updated to deal with spatial data types and can generate maps from them. Reporting Services reports can be exported as images, so I'm assuming that the generated maps can also be exported as images.